# IE8 Knockout 3.3.0 Error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

I'm not sure what is causing it, but IE8 points to the catch line in this code as causing an error which stops the page from loading. I really have no more clues as to what is causing it. I've even wrapped any reserved keywords in quotes to avoid conflicts in knockout.

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(orderedBindings, function(bindingKeyAndHandler) {
    // Note that topologicalSortBindings has already filtered out any nonexistent binding handlers,
    // so bindingKeyAndHandler.handler will always be nonnull.
    var handlerInitFn = bindingKeyAndHandler.handler["init"],
        handlerUpdateFn = bindingKeyAndHandler.handler["update"],
        bindingKey = bindingKeyAndHandler.key;

    if (node.nodeType === 8) {
        validateThatBindingIsAllowedForVirtualElements(bindingKey);
    }

    try {
        // Run init, ignoring any dependencies
        if (typeof handlerInitFn == "function") {
            ko.dependencyDetection.ignore(function() {
                var initResult = handlerInitFn(node, getValueAccessor(bindingKey), allBindings, bindingContext['$data'], bindingContext);

                // If this binding handler claims to control descendant bindings, make a note of this
                if (initResult && initResult['controlsDescendantBindings']) {
                    if (bindingHandlerThatControlsDescendantBindings !== undefined)
                        throw new Error("Multiple bindings (" + bindingHandlerThatControlsDescendantBindings + " and " + bindingKey + ") are trying to control descendant bindings of the same element. You cannot use these bindings together on the same element.");
                    bindingHandlerThatControlsDescendantBindings = bindingKey;
                }
            });
        }

        // Run update in its own computed wrapper
        if (typeof handlerUpdateFn == "function") {
            ko.dependentObservable(
                function() {
                    handlerUpdateFn(node, getValueAccessor(bindingKey), allBindings, bindingContext['$data'], bindingContext);
                },
                null,
                { disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: node }
            );
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        ex.message = "Unable to process binding \"" + bindingKey + ": " + bindings[bindingKey] + "\"\nMessage: " + ex.message;
        throw ex;
    }
});
```

Comment: what's the actual error thrown/displayed?

Comment: Can you share more code? What does your binding look like? What does the error say?

Comment: @dperry `Object doesn't support this property or method`


@RPNiemeyer I'm debugging something very old, there is far too much to narrow down where exactly it is coming from.

Comment: if you're catching an exception, you can narrow it down to the try block. step through each line to see where the exception is actually being generated

Comment: Hmm, no offense, but if you can't narrow it down to a small-as-possible repro, how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: What does the binding that is failing look like?

Answer (score 1):

If you've used **Knockout.js** in your project, at some point or another you've probably encountered the following error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding". The most likely cause is a typo somewhere or forgetting to change the context.. E.g. you are within a foreach binding and forget to use $parent.

This may cause further innerHtml error,which stops the page from loading js.